# Getting Scalar Value with pandas loc/iloc/at/iat/ix

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2.  I am iterating through df1 using iterrows, and for a particular field in each line, I am looking into df2 for the line that matches that field, and trying to pull out a corresponding value from that line in df2 in a SCALAR format.  Every way I try to do this I end up with another dataframe or series and I can't use that value as a scalar.  Here is my latest attempt:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    a = row[0]
    b = df2.loc[(df2['name'] == a ), 'weight']
    c = row[1] - b   #this is where error happens
    df1.set_value(index,'wtdif',c)
```

I get an error because 'b' in this case is not a scalar, if i print it out here is an example of what it looks like.  The '24' here is the index of the row it was found in in df2.  The other confusing part about this is that I can't index 'b' in any way even though it is a series (i.e. b[0] creates an error, as does b['weight'], etc.)

```
Name: weight, dtype: float64
24    141.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because the only index in `b` is 24.  You could use that or (more easily) index by location using,

```
b.iloc[0]
```

This is a common gotcha for new Pandas users.  Indices are preserved when pulling data out of a Series or DataFrame.   They do not, in general, run from 0 -> N-1 where N is the length of the Series or the number of rows in the DataFrame.

This will help a bit http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html although I admit it was confusing for me at first as well.

Comment: I've had a hard time making really good sense of the pandas documentation in general and have personally got caught by some problems regarding indices that I didn't even think possible. As Gabriel mentions the `b.iloc[0]` will pull the zeroth row of the dataframe. `b.iloc[0:5]` is going to pull the first five rows of the dataframe, regardless of what their proper index is.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I am still getting "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" when I make that change to my code.

Your suggestion makes a lot of sense though and does work, thanks for posting that.  I wrote a quick test script to verify the fix, and it did in fact work so thumbs up for that.  I'll post that code here in case anyone else is ever curious.

I'm missing something here, I'll just have to keep working on what is wrong and what my next question should be...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def foo(df1,df2):

    df1['D'] = 0

    for index,row in df1.iterrows():
        name = row[2]  #for some reason name ends up as column 3 in this dataframe rather than column 0?  whatever, not important, but strange
        temp = df2.loc[(df2['name'] == name), 'weight']
        x = row[3] + temp.iloc[0] #
        df1.set_value(index,'D',x)
    print df1


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['alex','bob', 'chris'], 'weight' : [140,150,160], 'A' : ['1','2','3'], 'B' : ['4','5','6']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['alex','bob', 'chris'], 'weight' : [180,190,200], 'C' : ['1','2','3'], 'D' : ['4','5','6']})
print df1
print df2

foo(df1,df2)
```